# Code to display high score table wont display in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, game-engine

Below is my code used within my game in android studio. The code seems to compile without any errors, however it does not seem to output in my textview within my Game over screen. Instead only the text textview is outputted. To provide context supplied an image of the Game Over output screen which shows only the text textview being shown.

```
package com.example.spaceattack;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EndActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button gameStart;
    private TextView numberScore;
    private String score;
    TextView table_score;
    int lastScore;
    int best1, best2, best3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_end);

        table_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.table_score);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        lastScore = preferences.getInt("lastScore", 0);
        best1 = preferences.getInt("best1", 0);
        best2 = preferences.getInt("best2", 0);
        best3 = preferences.getInt("best3", 0);

        if (lastScore > best3) {
            best3 = lastScore;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("best3", best3);
            editor.apply();
        }

        if (lastScore > best2) {
            int temp = best2;
            best2 = lastScore;
            best3 = temp;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("best3", best3);
            editor.putInt("best2", best2);
            editor.apply();
        }

        if (lastScore > best1) {
            int temp = best1;
            best1 = lastScore;
            best2 = temp;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("best2", best2);
            editor.putInt("best1", best1);
            editor.apply();
        }

        table_score.setText("LAST SCORE: " + lastScore + "\n" +
                "BEST1: " + best1 + "\n" +
                "BEST2: " + best2 + "\n" +
                "BEST3: " + best3);


        score = getIntent().getExtras().get("score").toString();

        gameStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart_btn);
        numberScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreCount);

        gameStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(EndActivity.this, WaterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        numberScore.setText("Score = " + score);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}






package com.example.spaceattack;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private SpaceShipView gameView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final static long Interval = 30;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameView = new SpaceShipView(this);
        setContentView(gameView);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        } else {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        gameView.invalidate();

                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, Interval);

    }
}
```

[image: enter image description here[][2]]

Comment: what you want to print in textview?
and show the code of other avctivity as welll

Comment: My bad got it to display in textview however now the number remains at 0. Want to develop a high score system. Provided an edit in the question. @WahdatKashmiri

Comment: Added code for MainActivity class and updated image of my end game screen